# Dealing with very large hex numbers in python

Tags: python, hex

I need to convert an extremely large number

`(760402852596084587359490684321824034940816612213847025986535451828145781910762684416)` to hexadecimal in python, but it seems to round it off when i run hex(N). What am I supposed to do? I've tried float.hex but that was fruitless

Said number yields `0x643437346d684000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

The resulting hex is supposed to be `0x643437346d696e3372535f43683334373372535f344e645f4c693452535f30685f6d79`

```
from sys import argv
print(hex(int(argv[1])))
```

Comment: why? whatfor? where is the number coming from? what do you need it in hex for? Curiosity? eulers?

Comment: I need it to convert to ASCII after Hex, and it's for RSA, I'm taking part in a puzzle where E=3, and I'm doing a cubed root attack to solve it

Comment: Check `int(hex(x), 16) == x`.  That is the correct hex representation of that number.

Comment: inb4 its rounding off numbers, i know the decrypted ascii that its supposed to translate into (hex->ascii), this one is cut off due to some weird rounding issue. Yes, they match up, but it rounds when checking too.

Comment: The original integer is an even number.  I don't see how this can translate into the claimed correct hex number which is odd.

Comment: Your "target" hex would be produced by the decimal number `760402852596092734681341892630266874604616529751992765702044492646143626468218858873`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's wrong? you can test the code below. The results are the same:

```
def make_hex(a):
    list = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
    output = []
    while a>1:
        output.append(list[a%16])
        a = a//16
    output.reverse()   
    return '0x' + ''.join(output)

a = 760402852596084587359490684321824034940816612213847025986535451828145781910762684416
print(make_hex(a))
print(hex(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your original number by converting it with a different function and then adding 1 by 1.

Answer: Python isn't truncating, the hex of your number just happens to end in 0s:

```
>>> num=760402852596084587359490684321824034940816612213847025986535451828145781910762684416
>>> to_bytes(num)
'643437346d684000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
>>> to_bytes(num+1)
'643437346d684000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'
>>> to_bytes(num+2)
'643437346d684000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002'
```

Here's my to_bytes function for reference:

```
def to_bytes(i, count=0, endian='big'):
    count = 1 if i < 256 else math.ceil(math.log(i + 1, 256))
    return i.to_bytes(count, endian).hex()
```