# converting 41digit float to hexadecimal

Tags: python, math, rsa, bigint

I am playing around with some RSA crypto calculations and one of them is calculating

`very-large-number**(1/3)`

where very large number is 100 digits. I need the result as hexadecimal in the end to get the final result.

I have tried the usual float.hex() hex(int(n)) and even some of the prosed solutions from here [Dealing with very large hex numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56299499/dealing-with-very-large-hex-numbers-in-python#)

but the result I get is either in scientific format (xx.xxxx+40) or the last half of the outout is all 0 (which I know is not correct)

Example:

```
>>> n=14887716705766614226302331656748546195328906880296894322596715261404953788693951344841626882745910926946567107240171862117
>>> ct=n**(1/3)
>>> ct.hex()
'0x1.212d39ed89671p+134'
>>> print(ct)
2.4600430019674926e+40
>>> print(ct.hex())
0x1.212d39ed89671p+134
hex(int(ct))
'0x484b4e7b6259c400000000000000000000'
>>> int(ct)
24600430019674926067273894051435979472896
```

so how do I get the hex value out ? the first part)0x484b4e7b6259c) from hex(int(ct)) is correct so this seem to indicate precision error.

I have also tried with numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x=np.longdouble(14887716705766614226302331656748546195328906880296894322596715261404953788693951344841626882745910926946567107240171862117)
>>> float_formatter='{e:f}'.format
>>> np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':float_formatter},precision=128)
>>> ct=np.cbrt(x)
>>> np.cbrt(x)
2.4600430019675053399e+40
>>> print(ct)
2.4600430019675053399e+40
```

Edit:
the actual result for the calculations should be: 24600430019675053398291607284547696341373 before hex which should turn into 0x484B4E7B625A2D53644D2D64644F72317D as hex

Comment: This is not how RSA works. At no point do you need to take a cube root. You have gone astray somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while Python integers are multi-precision numbers, floats are only 64 bits IEEE 754 floating point numbers and have a precision limited to 15 or 16 decimal digits.

That means that the floating point `n ** (1/3)` operation will only give an approximation.
But you could use Newton method to find a more accurate solution of the equation x**3 = n:

```
def sqr3(n):
    s0 = int(n ** (1/3))
    s1 = 0
    while True:
        s1 = s0 + (n - s0 **3) // 2 // s0 // s0
        if s1 ** 3 == n:
            break
        if (s0 - 1 <= s1 <= s0 + 1):
            # should search further whether s0 or s1 (or maybe next iteration)
            #  would be the best one...
            break
        s0 = s1
    return s1
```

It gives for `sqr3(n)`: `24600430019675053398291607284547696341373` which is the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick check with an existing **[online converter](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter)**, your two outputs are in fact the same number

```
'0x484b4e7b6259c400000000000000000000'
```

equals

```
24600430019674926067273894051435979472896
```

Comment: yes problem is that it is not the full result as it seems python cannot handle the precision needed for the cube root calculation when it turns it into a float behind the scenes.